# Adjusted output for looping through a directory

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

I have a bit of code that is directed to loop through a directory and display the results in a listbox.  I have everything working, but the output displays the entire file path (\server\directory\directory\subdirectory\filename.filetype) in the listbox.  Ideally, I would like this to display just the filename and the filetype (ie. workbook1.xlsm).

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Server\directory\Folder\Folder\", "*.xlsm", 
                     SearchOption.AllDirectories);
statusCodeLB.Items.Clear();
foreach (string file in filePaths)
{
    statusCodeLB.Items.Add(file);
}
statusLabel.Text = statusCodeLB.Items.Count.ToString();
```

Also, Is there any way to get this to be fully functional on a Mac OS X (10.6 and 10.7 to be precise)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have everything working, but the output displays the entire file path (\server\directory\directory\subdirectory\filename.filetype) in the listbox. Ideally, I would like this to display just the filename and the filetype (ie. workbook1.xlsm).

You are looking for `Path.GetFileName(path)`, documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx). The documentation reads as follows:

> Returns the file name and extension of the specified path string.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Server\directory\Folder\Folder\", "*.xlsm", 
                     SearchOption.AllDirectories);
statusCodeLB.Items.Clear();
foreach (string file in filePaths)
{
    statusCodeLB.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
statusLabel.Text = statusCodeLB.Items.Count.ToString();
```

If the file was (input) `"C:\Some\Directory\Structure\fileName.ext"` the resulting string added to the `ListBox.Items` would be (output) `fileName.ext`.

Comment: This might require a separate question...but how would I adjust it to not pull in temp files "~filename.ext"?

Comment: Separate question, ask it about further filtering files.

Comment: I will ask a separate question.  Thank you for the quick help on this one.